# Как построить диапазон значений от одной даты до другой

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с 3 колонками `(status, date_start, date_end)`.

```
(1, '2021-08-01 20:10:14', '2021-08-02 02:15:43')
```

Как из исходной получить следующее

```
(1, '2021-08-01 20:00')
(1, '2021-08-01 21:00')
(1, '2021-08-01 22:00')
 ....
(1, '2021-08-02 02:00')
```

По факту нужно построить диапазон значений от `date_start` до `date_end`

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. В разных СУБД это будет делаться совершенно по-разному.

Comment: @Akina postgresql

Comment: Что за опорная таблица

Comment: См. generate_series() и date_trunc(). *Что за опорная таблица* Сперва Вы написали MySQL 5.7 - это для него нужна опорная таблица.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается все делается через `generate_series`

```
select status, generate_series(
    date_trunc('hour', date_start),
    date_trunc('hour', date_end),
    interval '1 hour')
  from tab
```